# Cannot install vignette from an R package on GitHub

Tags: r, r-package, vignette

I coded an R package that is hosted on my GitHub. I included a vignette, and I can install the package and load the vignette without any issue from R and RStudio by doing:

```
devtools::install_github("rosalieb/serac", build_vignettes = TRUE)
library(serac)
vignette("serac")
```

However, I have a few colleagues who cannot install the vignette (the only way they can download the package is by doing `devtools::install_github("rosalieb/serac")` (default of build_vignettes is FALSE).
It works if they use RStudio, but not in 'regular' R.

I encourage people to use RStudio, but I cannot force them, and eventually, I do not understand why it would work in 'regular' R for me but not for them.

They tried to install pandoc, knitr, Rtools - none of these worked.

Here is the error message when my colleague tries to install the package with the vignette:

```
v  checking for file 'C:\Temp\RtmpO8YwVb\remotesf9842f1431\rosalieb-serac-46a3587/DESCRIPTION'

 
 
 
-  preparing 'serac':
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
 
   checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
 
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information

 
 
 
-  installing the package to build vignettes

 
 
 
   creating vignettes ...
 
   creating vignettes ...
 
E  creating vignettes (4.9s)
   --- re-building 'serac.Rmd' using rmarkdown
   Error: processing vignette 'serac.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   Pandoc is required to build R Markdown vignettes but not available. Please make sure it is installed.
   --- failed re-building 'serac.Rmd'
   
   RESUME : le traitement du fichier suivant a échoué :
     'serac.Rmd'
   
   Erreur : Vignette re-building failed.
   Exécution arrêtée

Erreur : Failed to install 'serac' from GitHub:
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: RStudio will make sure to install a version of pandoc. Regular R will not. Make sure you update your `PATH` environment variable and relaunch R after you install `pandoc` You can run `Sys.which("pandoc")` in regular R to verify that R can see the installed program. It should return a path to the executable, and not an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

The message indicates that `rmarkdown::render` can't find Pandoc.

It looks for it in three places:  in the directory specified by the `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` environment variable, in directories on the `PATH`, in the directory `opt/pandoc` in the user's home directory.  So your colleagues who have installed it should make sure it is available in one of those locations.  They can see the current values of the environment variables by running

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

and

```
Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")
```

Temporary changes can be made using

```
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/path/to/pandoc/directory")
```

This needs to happen in the session that is trying to install the package and build the vignette, not in the vignette itself.

How to make permanent changes to those values depends on the details of what system they are running.

Comment: What's annoying is that it violates widely established conventions for environment variables by using the wrong namespace. ‘rmarkdown’ isn’t RStudio. The variable should be called `RMARKDOWN_PANDOC` or similar. Setting an environment variable starting with `RSTUDIO_` shouldn’t influence third-party packages, and vice-versa.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the issue is that RStudio comes along with it's own version of `pandoc`. On my mac it's in `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/tools`. So if you had a system level pandoc, it would use that one instead presumably. In this case it doesn't have more to with the IDE I think than the package. You're right that setting `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` outside of RStudio will have no effect.

Comment: @MrFlick, did you try that?  It works for me.  (You don't set `RSTUDIO_PANDOC` to the path to the `pandoc` executable, you set it to the directory holding `pandoc`, i.e. `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/tools` in your case as in mine).

Comment: I guess I was going of the documentation in `?rmarkdown::pandoc_available` that says not to modify that variable. But now that I read it more closely, you are right. It will still use that variable, though I can't see where it reads it in the code.

Comment: Ah, OK. It is in the pandoc package source code and it does seem to prefer the rstudio version for some reason. https://github.com/cderv/pandoc/blob/74d8a6503a55c72bc3f5c030f8a4cfa6023ce91d/R/pandoc-bin.R#L36. Still it seems like the recommendation would be to change your PATH instead to be safer.

Comment: It's hard to write bulletproof instructions about how to change the PATH, since it uses a different format on Windows and Unix-alikes.  It also has wider side effects, since tons of software uses it, and permanent changes often turn out to be a bad idea.

Comment: @user2554330 Actually `PATH` can be set safely and easily in a cross-platform manner by doing the following: `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(newpath, Sys.getenv('PATH'), sep = .Platform$path.sep)`. And since the scope of this change is limited to the current process, this is perfectly safe to do. Alternatively this could be written into `.REnviron`.

Comment: That changes the meaning of system commands `deno` and `esbuild` on my system, because they happen to live in the same directory as `pandoc`.  I don't know what those do, so I don't know if that's safe or not.  Putting `newpath` last would be safer, but still has more side effects than what I put in my answer.

Comment: @MrFlick:  I think the search used by `rmarkdown` is the one in `rmarkdown::find_pandoc`, not the one you saw in the `pandoc` package.  (Maybe the next release of `rmarkdown` will change things.)  In that search, preference is given to the highest version number found; if there are ties, the home dir version beats the `PATH` which beats `RSTUDIO_PANDOC`.